# Docstring convention for Python __str__, __unicode__, and __repr__ class methods

Tags: python, documentation

What is the docstring convention in Python for the following "magic" class methods:

- `__str__`
- `__unicode__`
- `__repr__`

Should I add docstrings for these? If yes, what should they say (for each)?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't add docstrings; they'll never meaningfully differ from [the python stdlib docs relating to them](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization).